# Styled div renders with zero height

Tags: css, html, height

I ran into a quite annoying problem a few days ago. I'm working on a website with the following structure:

[header]
[menu strip]
[featured stuff]
[contents]
[footer]

(these are all horizontally centered divs under each other with the same fixed width in this order)

Later on I will change the contents of the "contents" part. Inside the "contents" div there will be other divs, sometimes with a fixed height and sometimes not.

Now here's the problem: any time I put another div into the "contents" without a declared height, the inner div renders with 0px. It doesn't matter if the inner div has elements with declared height or not. It works with declared heights, but I cannot guarantee that I will know the height of the contents at all times.

What could be causing this?

Comment: your css and html of your current structure would help to get an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a **[clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)** issue when elements inside the div are floating.

> The problem happens when a floated
>   element is within a container box,
>   that element does  not automatically
>   force the container’s height adjust to
>   the floated element.  When an element
>   is floated, its parent no longer
>   contains it because the float is
>   removed from the flow.

Comment: You can also try to give overflow: hidden; to the surrounding element. It often forces the browser to recalculate the hight.

Comment: Ahh, that's it! I've tried applying clear:both before and it didn't help, but clearfix just did the trick! Thanks!